# Magento 2 How to create an Extension for Shipping Calculator on Product Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to know that how to create an **Extension for Shipping Calculator** on product page .The functionality of Shipping Calculator is use Country , Region and Pincode on the product page. when I fill the all details and click on Calculate shipping button. It will show all relative shipping methods. It is similar to Estimate shipping block on cart but I need on product page.

Many [image]Thanks

Comment: I have find the code
app\code\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\EstimatePost.php where a conroller action but I am unable to use in my controller it is not working for me

Comment: I need the solution like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319514/how-to-show-shipping-costs-per-product-in-product-page-in-magento-1-9-1

Comment: did you find any solution @Dharmen ?

Comment: @DharmenGunawat any update?